# How many answers?

Tags: livewires, python

So,again I'm making a tables (math tables) checker to check your answers. I've used the search but nothing I found is relevant.

```
def math():
    for f in range (3):
        right=0
        wrong=0
        x=10
        c=5
        p=x*c
        print x,'times',c
        v=read_number('What is the answer?')
        if p==v:
            right=right+1
            print 'You got it right!'
        else:
            wrong=wrong+1
            print 'You got it wrong.'
    for h in range (1)
        print 'You got',right,'right, and',wrong,'wrong'
```

The problem is, when I do this, I get the last one wrong to test it, and it says:       'You got 0 right and 1 wrong' like it's not registering the answers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: how many times do you ask "What is the answer"?  How many times do you set `right=0` and `wrong=0`?  [PS: That can't be your code, there's a missing colon after `(1)`.]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a scope issue to me.

```
def math():
    for f in range (3):
        right=0
        wrong=0
```

should be

```
def math():
    right=0
    wrong=0
    for f in range (3):
```

so you don't reset `right` and `wrong` for each question.

Comment: Seconding this answer.  The counts get reset on every iteration.